# Statistical graphical models in practice

Tags: bayesian-network, java

I've followed the probabilistic graphical models course in coursera and now I would like to apply what I've learnt with real data.

I want to implement LDA on a large corpus of text and I was wondering if there is any Java/Scala library I can feed with the structure of the graphical model and the values of the observed variables and automatically learn the parameters by computing the Maximum Likelihood Estimator (notice that in LDA there is one latent variable, which is not observed).

I've already experimented with pyMC but I ended up creating an observed variable for each word (and thus a latent variable) and building the graph took lot of memory and time.

Any library suggestion is more than welcome as well as pointers to easy tutorials and documentations.

Cheers!